# Arrays Multidimensionales en php

Tags: php, vscode, php8

necesito generar una pseudo base de datos con arrays asociativos y multidimensionales. Explico.
Se piden los datos de un libro (nombre, editorial, etc.) y se guardan en un array asociativo. Este array se debe guardar en un array multidimensional que funcionara como una base de datos, donde se deben almacenar los primeros (array asociativo con datos de los libros)¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?¿Hay manera de hacer comparativas entre un trim y un valor de un array? Muchas gracias!

Disculpen si el código es desprolijo, además esta incompleto. Es para un trabajo académico y estoy tratando de hacerlo lo mejor posible! cualquier comentario es de ayuda y me permite crecer! sigo escribiendo porque la pagina me pide mas detalles.

inserto código

```
<?php
/**
 * Arreglo I; Base de Datos de Productos
 * @param array $BDProductos
 * return String
 */

function baseDatos($codigo){
    $BDProductos=[];
    $i=0;
    $libro=["codigo"=>"","editorial"=>"","nombre"=>"","cantEjemplares"=>"","precioUnitario"=>""];
    if($codigo == $libro["codigo"]){
        echo "\nEL libro ya existe en la Base de Datos.";
    }elseif($codigo <> $libro["codigo"]){
        echo "\n¿Cual es le código del libro?>> ";
        $libro["codigo"] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        echo "\n¿Cual es la editorial?>> ";
        $libro["editorial"] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        echo "\n¿Cual es el nombre?>> ";
        $libro["nombre"] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        echo "\n¿Cuantas unidad ingresan?>> ";
        $libro["cantEjemplares"] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        echo "\n¿Cual es el precio por libro?>> ";
        $libro["precioUnitario"] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        echo "\n-¡Libro Agregado con Exito!-\n";
        array_push($BDProductos,$libro);
        print_r($BDProductos);
        echo "Datos del Libro\n";
        foreach($libro as $dato => $valor){
            echo $dato." >>".$valor."\n";
        }  
    }
    echo "\n¿Que queires hacer ahora?
    [1] >>Menú Administrativo<<
    [2] Salir del Programa ";
    $elegir=trim(fgets(STDIN));
    if($elegir=="1"){
        usuarios("admin","admin");
    }elseif($elegir==2){
        echo "\nAdios!";
    }else{
        echo "\nERROR; La opcion elegida no existe.";
    }
}

 /**
 * Modulo ?; Acciones del Admin
 * @param Enteros $accionesAdmin
 * @param String  
 *
 */

 function admin($accionesAdmin){
     if($accionesAdmin == 1){
        echo "\n¿Cual es le código del libro?>> ";
        $codigo= trim(fgets(STDIN));
        baseDatos($codigo);
     }elseif($accionesAdmin == 2){
         /**Mostrar Libros Por Editorial */
     }elseif($accionesAdmin == 3){
            /**Mostrar total de los libros Registrados */
     }elseif($accionesAdmin == 4){
         /**Corregir informacion de un Libro por codigo */
     }elseif($accionesAdmin == 5){
         /**Variar Stock (Aumentar o Disminuir)*/
     }elseif($accionesAdmin == 0){
         /**Programa Cerrado */
     }
     else{
         echo "\nERROR; Accion inexistente.";
     }
 }

 /**
 * Modulo ?; Tipo de Usuario 
 * @param String $usuario, $contraseña, $admin, $invitado
 * return String
 */

 function usuarios($usuario, $contraseña){
     if($usuario == "invitado" && $contraseña == "invitado"){
     /** */
     }elseif($usuario == "admin" && $contraseña == "admin"){

        echo "\n >>Menú Administrativo<<
        ¿Que desea hacer?
        [1] Agregar Libro
        [2] Mostrar Libos Por Editorial
        [3] Mostrar Registro Libros
        [4] Corregir infromacion de un Libro
        [5] Variar Stock
        [0] Salir
        >>Ingresa el número entre corchetes<<  ";
        $accionesAdmin = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        admin($accionesAdmin);
    }else{
        echo "\nERROR; El usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden con el registro de usarios de la empresa.";
    }
 }


            
 /**
  * Programa Principal
  * @param string $usuario, $contraseña
  */

  echo "\n-Usuario- > ";
  $usuario = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  echo "\n-Contraseña- > ";
  $contraseña = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  usuarios($usuario,$contraseña);
```

Comment: que has intentado ???

Comment: Hasta ahora intente crear un contador $i++ que agrega un indice mas cada que se agrega un indice asociativo, pero no queda guardado $i++;
        echo "\n¿Cual es le código del libro?>> ";
        $libro["codigo"] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        echo "\n¿Cual es el nombre?>> ";
        $libro["nombre"] = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        echo "\n-¡Libro Agregado con Exito!-\n";
        $BDProductos[$i++]=$libro; <-- este es el contador que agrega indices

Comment: te falta mas investigación ... y por decir investigación ... es buscar como crear una base de datos y como guardar esos datos como leerlos y como modificarlos ...

Comment: pues es un trabajo de fin de semestre. Estoy haciendolo con todos los datos que nos dieron en la cursada... ¿donde puedo leer sobre esto? gracias!

Comment: que tienes instalado ??? xamp, laragon, wamp??

Comment: unicamente nos dieron php con editor en vscode, no nos enseñaron nada de msql... por eso no entiendo como quieren que haga una base de datos jajajja

Comment: Entonces eso debes preguntárselo a tu profesor ... solo el sabe lo que espera que haga el programa ... ni siquiera sabes que es una base de datos ... ese termino debe explicarlo el profesor ...

Comment: Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: en el sitio resolvemos problema específicos cuando tu código de un error que no sepas como resolver ... no nos dedicamos a diseñar y explicar bases de datos ... para que te ayudemos con tu trabajo final de semestre debes tu de estar clara de lo que tienes que hacer, demostrar que has investigado y indicar con que código tienes problema...